# Using Bad Json in Python

Tags: python, json

I am having a json in a file which i want to access in my Python Code. The Json file looks like :

```
{
    "fc1" : {
        region : "Delhi",
        marketplace : "IN"
    },
    "fc2" : {
        region : "Rajasthan",
        marketplace : "IN"
    }
}
```

- The above json i want to use in my Python code. I want to access according to its keys("fc1", "fc2")
- Since this is not like actual json, i am facing difficulty in accessing the values in json.

Is there any way in python language to access these type of json.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as "dirty JSON". What you've pasted is simply not JSON – it might be a valid JavaScript object, and as such look mostly like JSON, but it's not JSON. You really should just acquire an actual JSON file first; anything else is a lot of work, or a hack.

Comment: If you have that text in a file then its *not* `json`. If someone gave you that file then give it back to them quick. If *you* generated that file, then you should put quotes around `region` and `marketplace`.

Comment: There is no "dirty JSON". It's not JSON if it is not valid. In your case it might be valid Yaml.

Comment: do you need a generic way? Otherwise, you might be good with replacing your unquoted keys with quoted ones before parsing. 

If you need a generic solution and you don't find an existing one you could think about making your own "dirty-JSON"-parser e.g. with [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark). There is even an example for a regular JSON parser on which you could build.

Comment: there is module [dirtyjson](https://github.com/codecobblers/dirtyjson) which tries to read incorrect JSON

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that, if you generated that file, then you should put quotes around region and marketplace when generating it (or have the person who generated it do the same). However, if this absolutely isn't an option for whatever reason, the following approach might work:

```
import json
data_string = """
{
    "fc1":{
        region:"Delhi",
        marketplace: "IN"
    },
    "fc2" : {
        region:"Rajasthan",
        marketplace: "IN"
    }
}
"""
data = json.loads(data_string.replace('region', '"region"').replace('marketplace', '"marketplace"'))
data
>>>{'fc1': {'region': 'Delhi', 'marketplace': 'IN'},
 'fc2': {'region': 'Rajasthan', 'marketplace': 'IN'}}
```

Note that you would have to do the same for any unquoted key.

Answer (score 0):

There is module [dirtyjson](https://github.com/codecobblers/dirtyjson) which reads this incorrect JSON.

```
import dirtyjson

data_string = """
{
    "fc1":{
        region:"Delhi",
        marketplace: "IN"
    },
    "fc2" : {
        region:"Rajasthan",
        marketplace: "IN"
    }
}
"""

data = dirtyjson.loads(data_string)
print(data)
print(data['fc1'])
print(data['fc2'])
```